# Sort a list containing dates in string format: MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: python, list, date, sorting

### Issue

Below is a list of dates in the string format(MM/DD/YYYY).
I'm trying to sort them in ascending order(oldest to most-recent date) using `.sort()` but getting wrong results.

### List before sort

```
listOfDates = ['07/25/2022', '07/19/2022', '04/19/2022', '02/18/2022', '01/18/2022', '10/20/2021', '10/27/2021', '11/26/2021', '12/23/2021', '01/05/2022', '01/07/2022', '01/18/2022', '01/21/2022', '01/24/2022', '02/24/2022', '02/25/2022', '03/16/2022', '03/25/2022', '04/29/2022', '05/10/2022', '05/11/2022', '05/31/2022', '06/08/2022', '06/10/2022', '06/13/2022', '06/14/2022', '07/14/2022']
```

### Results using `listOfDates.sort()`

The problem here is that it appears to be sorting by month and not chronologically.
Notice it starts at `01/05/2022` and goes up to `07/25/2022` and then continues at `10/20/2021` until ending `12/23/2021`

```
['01/05/2022', '01/07/2022', '01/18/2022', '01/18/2022', '01/21/2022', '01/24/2022', '02/18/2022', '02/24/2022', '02/25/2022', '03/16/2022', '03/25/2022', '04/19/2022', '04/29/2022', '05/10/2022', '05/11/2022', '05/31/2022', '06/08/2022', '06/10/2022', '06/13/2022', '06/14/2022', '07/14/2022', '07/19/2022', '07/25/2022', '10/20/2021', '10/27/2021', '11/26/2021', '12/23/2021']
```

### Expecting

That the dates are ordered in the list by descending order with the first element starting `10/20/2021` and the final element in the list is `07/25/2022`

Comment: Well, you're sorting strings, not dates.

Comment: You are sorting them according to their string values. Instead, sort them according to their date value. You can parse them to dates using `datetime.strptime` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Why do you expect strings to be sorted as dates? If you want to sort them as dates, specify a `key` argument to `.sort()` which converts the string to a date. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

Comment: I recommend using the datetime module. 
Personally, I would iterate through your list and convert each date to a datetime object in a new list. Then, you can use sort functions in the module that intelligently will base the sort on chronology.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
import datetime

sortedDates = sorted([datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%m/%d/%Y') for item in listOfDates])

[item.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for item in sortedDates]
```